# How to pass argument to the functions called using clokwerk library

Tags: rust

The following is MVP of what I am doing

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

use clokwerk::Interval::*;
use clokwerk::TimeUnits;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: u16,
}

pub fn print_debug_person(person_arc: Arc<Person>) {
    println!("Person is  :{:?}", person_arc)
}


fn main() {
    let p = Person { name: "Asnim".to_string(), age: 10 };

    let p = Arc::new(p);
    let mut scheduler = clokwerk::Scheduler::new();

    for loop_period in 1..5 {
        let person_arc = p.clone();
        scheduler.every(loop_period.seconds()).run(move || print_debug_person(person_arc));
    }

    loop {
        scheduler.run_pending();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
}
```

Here the code fails with error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `person_arc`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:27:79
   |
26 |         let person_arc = p.clone();
   |             ---------- captured outer variable
27 |         scheduler.every(loop_period.seconds()).run(move || print_debug_person(person_arc));
   |                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `person_arc` has type `Arc<Person>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

What am I doing wrong here. What change should I make so that arc can be passed to this function?
Isn't `Arc` the right structure to use?
I wont able able add `Copy` trait to the struct as `String` doesn't implement `Copy` trait. Right?

Dependencies

```
clokwerk = "0.3.5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `print_debug_person` *takes* ownership of the value given to it, so calling it with `person_arc` will attempt to *move* it. However, since the closure is intended to be called multiple times, this would leave the value invalid for future calls.

To fix this, you can either make a new `Arc<Person>` each time by cloning it:

```
scheduler.every(loop_period.seconds()).run(move || print_debug_person(person_arc.clone()));
```

---

Or, since your function doesn't seem to *need* ownership, it should just borrow the `Person`:

```
pub fn print_debug_person(person: &Person) {
    println!("Person is  :{:?}", person)
}
```

Which you can call with a `&Arc<Person>` due to deref coercion:

```
scheduler.every(loop_period.seconds()).run(move || print_debug_person(&person_arc));
```